# How to stripe rows with jQuery while excluding some particular rows

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following to stripe rows:

```
$(".stripeMe tr:even").addClass("alt");
```

I have a table with some rows.  To mark the rows for the user I set one (or more rows) to have

```
style="background-color: red;"
```

Is there a way to continue to use my existing way of striping rows yet leave that one row different?  I want to say "Add the class alt to all even rows except when I tell you not to"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about use a class to style the user rows instead of the inline style. Then you can do:
`$('.stripeMe tr:even:not(.user)').addClass('alt')`

I think I've got the syntax right on that, but not 100% sure.

Comment: I ended up with $(".stripeMe tr:even:not(.noStripeMe)").addClass("alt");  that way I can give any row the .noStripeMe class and it will be left as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".stripeMe tr:even").each(function(){

     $(this).addClass("alt");

});
```

Inline styles will override class change.